# Fazer com que as variáveis criadas com lapply sejam alocadas no seu respectivo dataframe dentro de uma lista

Tags: r

Uso a função `lapply` e desejo que os resultados retornem dentro do seu respetivo dataframe dentro da lista. Considere a função a seguir:

```
x<-lapply(list,function(x)paste(x$Sigla,x$Município,sep='')) # onde `Sigla` e `Município`são variáveis em comum em todos os dataframes
```

Isso me retorna uma lista `x` apenas com os resultados (concatenados).

Como ajustar esta função para obter o que desejo?

**Não consigo postar o `dput`, pois a lista é muito grande.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usando o seguinte exemplo:

```
lista <- list(
  A = data.frame(Sigla = sample(LETTERS, 20, rep = T), Município = sample(letters, 20, rep = T)),
  B = data.frame(Sigla = sample(LETTERS, 20, rep = T), Município = sample(letters, 20, rep = T)),
  C = data.frame(Sigla = sample(LETTERS, 20, rep = T), Município = sample(letters, 20, rep = T))
)
```

Você pode usar alocar a nova variável dentro do seu respectivo dataframe com o comando `cbind`:

```
lapply(lista, function(x)cbind(x, Variável = paste(x$Sigla,x$Município,sep='')))
```